# Configuração VS Code para Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide, editor-de-texto, editor

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Tenho uma duvida, sobre como ocultar esses arquivos que o mac gera dentro do Visual Studio Code.

Alguém conhece alguma forma de ocultar esses ._arquivos.extencao? Pois atrapalha muito ao se organizar dentro do explorador.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc tem que adicionar esses arquivos na listagem de exclusão. Isso é até uma funcionalidade default do VS Code, Basta seguir esses passos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare na imagem acima que por padrão o VS CODE já trata essas extensões

```
  "files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true
  },
```

Mas no seu caso para excluir da listagem esses arquivos que começam com `._` vc deve fazer assim:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/._*": true
}
```

Comment: Shoow, obrigado cara, já estava ficando loco com essa bagunça kkk

Comment: @JuniorRocha legal que resolveu ai, ainda bem que temos essas opções para configurar rss. Boa sorte ai, Abs

Answer (score 0):

1. Pressione F1 no vscode
2. Digite: Workspace
3. Vá para: **Preferences: Open Workspace Settings**
4. Digite: files.exclude
5. Adicione novas entradas de Arquivos que quer 'Excluir' / 'Ocultar'
6. Pronto